# regedit command results in "access denied" in cmd

Tags: windows-7, command-line, permissions, uac

**Edit:** The issue at this point is that a regular user is granted access to the registry and there is no prompt for administrative credentials whatsoever. Prior to changing permissions (See Scott's answer below) even an admin received an "Access Denied" error. After changing permissions any user can access regedit.

How do I get the system to prompt for admin credentials and then use them to run?

When executing "regedit" from either the "run" prompt or the command prompt I receive access denied error messages.

On the other systems on my network the user is prompted for administrative credentials instead of receiving an error. On this system there is no prompt. From the "Run" prompt I receive the error after typing Regedit:

> "Windows cannot access the specified device, 
>   path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item"

From the command prompt I receive an error that simply states "Access denied".

If I escalate the command prompt (run it as an administrator) then regedit runs just fine. The problem is that the lack of a prompt for credentials might be related to other issues on the system.

As a note, using "mstsc" to attempt a remote desktop connection also causes this same problem. More "run" commands may do the same, though I have not tested this.

Is there a setting that forces a prompt instead of just giving an error?

Comment: What is the user's UAC level set at?

Comment: @Wutnaut is right, UAC handle that behavior

Comment: It is set to "Always notify". Would be nice if it notified lol...

Comment: Maybe check your user-account's permissions on the actual file regedit.exe. Perhaps those are messed up somehow and you cannot read/execute the file, thus no UAC prompt.

Comment: Good thought however permissions on SysWow64 (and Regedit.exe) appear to be identical on this system to other systems that are not experiencing the error. Also worth noting that I am logged in as a domain administrator.

Comment: 'PATH = C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\' I also copied the PATH variable from a working system but that did not resolve it. I checked the local security policy 'Windows Settings>Local Policies>Security Options" and the "UAC Behavior Of Elevation Prompt For Regular users" is "Prompt for Credentials". Odd. I will try the regedit rename. I see regedit located in "C:\Windows" and "C:\Windows\SysWow64" and in a folder named "winsxs" with a folder that has a GUID in it... Not sure which one it should be referencing.

Comment: Ok - renaming the Regedit file in "C:\Windows" caused a "not recognized" error and changed from "access denied". When I try to view the permissions of "C:\Windows\regedit.exe" it says `To continue, you must be an administrative user with permission to view this object's security properties.` The permissions listed include System, Administrators and TrustedInstaller.

Comment: Well, on my (Windows 7) box, “Users” have Read & Execute permission to `regedit.exe`. I can view file properties (including security properties; i.e., ownership and permissions), and read the `exe` file in `Notepad`, without getting a UAC prompt. But if I run it, I get the UAC prompt. So, I believe @TheUser1024 got it – the file permissions are set wrong.

Comment: BTW, when you respond to comment (in a new comment), it’s conventional to mention the author’s name, preceded by “@”, as in “@Scott”. That way I get notified. (I was able to respond to your last comment in a timely manner because I _just happened_ to check in on this question a half-hour after you posted it.) You can abbreviate, e.g., “@Scot”, or use an entire name (without spaces), e.g., “@ QuijoteShin”. The author of a post is automatically notified of comments to that post. See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [this help page](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @Scott Very true I forgot to put the @ symbol, my apologies. And the permissions are definitely different on regedit! The "Users" group was missing. If I add the users group with read / read & execute permissions it pulls up regedit, but it never prompts for credentials at all... Seems like there is no middle ground.

Comment: (1) This is beginning to sound like a new question. I suggest that you create a New Question. Cross-link them if you want. (2) For clarification: are you saying that a non-Administrator user can run `regedit` directly from Windows (Start Menu or `(Win)`+`(R)`) or a non-privileged Command Prompt (without a UAC dialogue)? (3) And can he then modify HKLM settings? Because users are normally able to view HKLM and modify HKCU.

Answer (score 1):

As [conjectured](https://superuser.com/questions/775675/regedit-command-access-denied#comment1008474_775675) by [TheUser1024](https://superuser.com/users/168802/theuser1024) and [confirmed](https://superuser.com/questions/775675/regedit-command-access-denied#comment1009186_775675) by the OP, the problem seems to be that “Users” don’t have Read & Execute permission to `regedit.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However my concern is that I am never prompted to elevate the user credentials. I would like for a regular user account to type `regedit` into the run prompt and for UAC to prompt for admin credentials. After changing permissions it never prompts for credentials at all, just executes as a regular user, which it shouldn't do at all!